# memory issue iPad 4.2 crashes

Tags: ipad, memory-management, device

I am developing a application which receives 600-700 KB of XML data from the server. I have to do some manipulations in that data so once received the data the memory increases to 600 KB to 2 M.B. Already view occupied 4 M.B of memory in the application. 
So while processing the XML data i m doing some manipulation(pre-parsing) and the memory increases to 600 K.B to 2 M.B and finally decreases to 600 K.B. due to increase in memory, application gives the memory warning. While getting memory warning i m releasing all the views in the navigation controller but it releases only 1 M.B of memory. Even though I release all the views the application is crashing. 
Please help me out in this issue. It happens in iPad 4.2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using 6-7 MB of memory does not sound like enough to make your app crash. Have you confirmed that your app's running out of memory is the actual cause of the crash (look at the crash log)?

Comment: ya I have checked that. It happens only in iPad 4.2 which has multitasking functionality. If I decrease the number of applications running in the background. my application works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magical answer here. You're using too much memory and you need to figure out how to use less. Without knowing more about your application it's difficult to be specific, though clearly loading in nearly 1Mb of data and playing around with it isn't helping.

Maybe you can stream the data rather than loading it all into memory? There's an open source library that helps: [StreamingXMLParser](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master/StreamingXMLParser).

Also, your view sounds huge (over a megabyte!). I'm sure there's some optimisation that can be performed there. Use Instruments to see where your memory is being used.

Comment: Actually I m loading the data in the fifth view controller. I am using navigation controller to load the view controllers. I can't parse data by streaming because I have to replace many special characters in the received data. My question is how the other applications are working perfectly. They won't occupy that much  memory to run the application?

Comment: We can't tell based in what you've told us. If your app is being ejected for using too much memory, you'll have to find a way of using less; what the other apps are doing is irrelevant. You need to measure (profile) your app to find where the memory is being used, make sure memory is being released when you think is and optimise where you're using a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe only 1MB is released because of a parameter value which can be altered or you may need to manually start a garbage collection operation during your development session, if relevant to the language in use. You could sectionalise the xml input if possible or you could invoke [your own] compact or compress of the xml when stored if you have access to the script or code in a way that allows it.